# Создание корзины на Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Здрвствуйте, помогите разобраться.
Пытаюсь создать корзину, в вьюхе написал:

```
<%= button_to 'Добавить в корзину', line_items_path(item_id: item) %>
```

в line_item_controller:

```
@cart = current_cart
item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(item: item)
```

получаю ощибку:

```
undefined local variable or method `item' for #<#<Class:0x00000004f509c0>:0x00000004f5fb78>
```

Пробовал тот-же код прописать в item_controller, тогда получаю:

```
Couldn't find Item without an ID
```

UPD: я пытась сделать как в книге "Гибкая разработка", там написано именно так, если я объявляю переменные как член объекта ничего не меняется, ошибки те же...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы переменные были доступны во вьюшках их нужно объявлять как члены объекта:

```
@item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(item: @item)
```

и

```
<%= button_to 'Добавить в корзину', line_items_path(item_id: @item) %>
```

Comment: я пытась сделать как в книге "Гибкая разработка", там написано именно так, если я объявляю как член объекта ничего не меняется, ошибки теже...